# How to use ReportViewerControl for Windows Desktop Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, report-viewer2010

I am new to Windows Desktop Application Development.

I have two tables in Access 2007 database.

First is the "Bill Master" and the second is "Bill Detail"

I want to print the bill from my application using the report viewer control.

How do I accomplish this?

Please help.

Comment: I took a windows form. Put the report viewer control and also put the button containing the Print option. But Sir I don't know how to configure and display data. Searched a lot for tutorial but could not get the proper way to learn from scratch @Stephen Bauer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this video](http://vimeo.com/7606689) to get to know how to create a report viewer control. Moreover, you will need to bind your data from the access database using e.g. this function

```
 public void LoadDatabase()
 {
     string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};", yourDatabaseName);

     using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
     {
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            var data = new DataSet();

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM A", con);
            adapter.Fill(data, "a");

            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM B", con);
            adapter.Fill(data, "b");

            // TODO: bind the control's data source to dataset
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir. But there is a problem that I am using Visual-Studio 2010 and video displays the designing of Visual - Studio 2008.

And the VS 2010 contains different designing patterns. So I am unable to solve this. @alex555

Comment: I'm using VS2012 and the design wizard is nearly the same. The only thing you have to do is to select a database (data source Microsoft Access Database File for your mdb-File) in the wizard instead of object. Or you can call `LoadDatabase()` within your `OnButtonClick`-Function. Don't be afraid, just try it! ;)

Comment: I selected the database in the design report wizard. In database there are two tables. Bill Master and Bill Details. Master Details should be displayed once and the Bill Detail I want to display in tabular format. But while arranging fields I am able to see the fields of single table only. And the wizard compulsorily demands "Values" field. I cannot understand what is that for.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know a lot about report viewer control. Here are some informations ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251724%28v=vs.100%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251724%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) about how to bind to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links will help you:

- http://www.gotreportviewer.com/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms251671.aspx